# How do I pass an instantiation of QCommandLineParser to a function in Qt?

Tags: qt, configuration, qt5, qcommandlineparser

Currently I have a working Qt command line application. However, I need to refactor this working program such that my QCommandLineParser object gets configured in a class method rather than in main() itself. I have tried the obvious:

In ExecuteTask.h:

```
void setUp(QCommandLineParser parser);
```

In ExecuteTask.cpp:

```
void ExecuteTask::setUp(QCommandLineParser parser){
    parser.setApplicationDescription("Learning console app in Qt");
    parser.addHelpOption();
}
```

In main.cpp:

```
    ...
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    ExecuteTask cmnd_line_func;
    QCommandLineParser parser;
    cmnd_line_func.setUp(parser);
    ...
```

However, I get this error (attached in link): 
[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSk37.png)

I have also tried declaring QCommandLineParser parser as a pointer in ExecuteTask.h but obviously this leads to problems when you have to run:

```
parser.process(app)
```

in main. I have tried actually also passing `QCoreApplication app` to my setUp function to run `parser.process(app)` in my `setUp()` method but that brought up similar "...is private within this context".

Also tried another solution where declaring `QCommandLineParser parser` as a pointer and using a `getParser()` method to return the parser in main but this lead to similar "private" problems.

-- no idea where to go from here as I'm used to C++ and just passing argc and argv to methods but this with Qt is different.

**So is there a way that QCommandLineParser can be passed to a method outside of main()?** The docs didn't much help me and just about every tutorial I've come across has all configuration done in main() and this is not what I want to do at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after mucking around, I found the solution.
in ExecuteTask.h:

```
void setUp(QCommandLineParser *parser);
```

in ExecuteTask.cpp:

```
void ExecuteTask::setUp(QCommandLineParser *parser){
    parser->setApplicationDescription("Learning console app in Qt");
    parser->addHelpOption();
}
```

in main.cpp:

```
    ExecuteTask cmnd_line_func;
    QCommandLineParser parser;

    cmnd_line_func.setUp(&parser);

    parser.process(app);
```